# How to insert parentheses in an eval statement to order operations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, eval

This is the Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rw0j2orqmp

The file this is in is reducers.js

I'm building a React/Redux calculator app, and currently I'm in the process of making the output display the results of the current calculation held in state. It works without parentheses but calculates the whole formula rather than a piece at a time. To fix this I wanted to wrap each piece in parentheses to have it calculate separately, taking off the method and then sticking it back on when the  first part is finished calculating by doing this:

```
value:
          methods.indexOf(state.lastValue) < 0
            ? eval("(" + state.calc.slice(0, -1) + ")" + state.calc.slice(-1) + state.value)
            : state.value,
```

but when I have it like that, I get "Unexpected token ) " .

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, and or is there a functional replacement for eval() in this case?

Comment: what does this mean ? `"(" + state.calc.slice(0, -1) + ")"

Comment: If I were to press 7 + 3 * 2 + on the calculator, in the display I want it to show the cumulated result, i.e. 7 + 3 = 10 * 2 = 20. without the parentheses, it calculates 7 + 3 * 2 and shows 13, but I want it to calculate (7+3) * 2 and show 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using eval or parentheses here. Is there a reason why this won't work for you?:

```
methods.indexOf(state.lastValue) < 0
  ? state.calc.slice(0, -1) + state.calc.slice(-1) + state.value
  : state.value
```

If you need to group things together, just use parentheses without the eval.

```
methods.indexOf(state.lastValue) < 0
  ? ((state.calc.slice(0, -1)) + state.calc.slice(-1) + state.value)
  : state.value
```

**Update**: I see what you're saying, sorry, it was hard to understand from your original explanation and I was on my mobile and couldn't really inspect your sandbox.

I'm thinking it may be better to keep a string that you can evaluate simply later, for example, if you have `"7 + 3"` stored and press `*`, turn wrap that original string in parentheses and add the `*`, resulting in `"(7 + 3) *"`, etc. Then whenever you want to show the result, you just evaluate that single stored calculation.

If you insist on doing eval that way, I'll just tell you that it works. For example, try this in the console:

```
eval("(" + "7 + 3" + ")" + "* 2")
// 20
```

So you may be doing something wrong with the values you are returning from the slice, which results in an eval error.
Try console logging that whole expression to see what's actually going on.

Comment: This shows the calculation instead of the result. I need to display the result in the display. What  you've suggested shows e.g. "7 + 3 +" in the calc box and "7 + 3" in the display box. I want it to show "7 + 3 +" in the calc box and "10" in the display box, just like a normal calculator

Comment: I've added my response as an update to the answer, as it was too long to paste as a comment.

Comment: Got it with this ternary : `? state.calc.length > 0 ? eval("(" + state.calc.slice(0, -1) + ")" + state.calc.slice(-1) + state.value ) : undefined` Thanks for the direction!